# FTPClient not letting me write with InputStream

Tags: java, ftp, ftp-client

I have a java piece that will FTP a string (long text document) to a remote location.  All seems to be working, but I am getting a very long hang time when ftp.storeFile(a,b) is called.  This then returns a replyCode 425.  It is odd because myData.txt is appearing inside the remote destination, but it is blank.  There must be something blocking the input stream?  Does anyone know what the issue could be?

Java code:

```
public void doFTP(){      
       FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
       FTPClientConfig config = new FTPClientConfig();
       ftp.configure(config);
       boolean error = false;
       try {
         int reply;
         String server = "example.com";
         ftp.connect(server);
         ftp.login(username, password);
         reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
         if(!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
           ftp.disconnect(); 
         } 
         InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(myString.getBytes()); //String
         ftp.setFileType(ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE, ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
         ftp.setFileTransferMode(ftp.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
         Boolean test = ftp.storeFile("myData.txt", is);  //FTP store here
         System.out.println(test);
         reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
         System.out.println(reply);
         is.close();
         ftp.logout();
       } catch(IOException e) {
       // ... not important
       } finally {
       // ... not important
       }
 }
```

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? You'd never know since, you are catching them but not logging/printing.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing looks strange to me.  where you have the *InputStream is =*
this code should be inside the **try { ..... }** code block.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem, I need to switch it to:

```
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
```

I still don't quite understand why this needs to be done, if anyone could care to explain.